# Best approach to obtain minutes passed from a resourse creation?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5, time, formatting

I need to pass to my view the time in minutes passed by an order submission. What is the best way to achieve that in Laravel and PHP?
I've tried that but not working very well:
`$order->minutes = (new DateTime($order->created_at))->diff(new DateTime("now"))->format('%I');`

Comment: Use Unix timestamps, then you can just subtract and divide by 60.  `time() - strtotime($order->created_at)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Laravel you can use Carbon for this.

```
$order->minutes = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($order->created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is like this (using Unix timestamps):

```
$submitted = '2018-10-11 10:00:00';

$diff = time() - strtotime($submitted);
//for minutes
if($diff > 0) $diff = floor($diff / 60);

echo $diff;
```